# How to separate values and keys in a CSV file with python that is turned into a dictionary with python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, key, key-value-store

I have a csv data set that opened used the DictReader in python and I would like the separate the keys and values.

```py
import csv

with open ('student_marks.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for keys in csv_reader:
        print(keys)
```

I have this output and I wish to separate the keys and values in the out put

```
{'Student ID': '4665178', 'Homework Total (20%)': '95.9', 'Project 1 (10%)': '91.9', 'Midterm (20%)': '91.2', 'Project 2 (10%)': '90.9', 'Final (40%)': '99'}
{'Student ID': '4665187', 'Homework Total (20%)': '83.1', 'Project 1 (10%)': '83', 'Midterm (20%)': '75.7', 'Project 2 (10%)': '92', 'Final (40%)': '78.6'}
{'Student ID': '4665203', 'Homework Total (20%)': '89.9', 'Project 1 (10%)': '73.6', 'Midterm (20%)': '98.9', 'Project 2 (10%)': '84.1', 'Final (40%)': '95.2'}
{'Student ID': '4665219', 'Homework Total (20%)': '81.3', 'Project 1 (10%)': '88.5', 'Midterm (20%)': '84.8', 'Project 2 (10%)': '81.2', 'Final (40%)': '91.1'}
```

Comment: What exactly is the expected output? What do you meant to separate the keys and values in the output. If you don't want dict why use `csv.DictReader`, maybe there is better approach based on expected output.

Comment: I was want to be able to separate keys such as Student ID, Homework,Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in method like this:

```
import csv

with open('student_marks.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for i in csv_reader:
        print(list(i.keys()))
        print(list(i.values()))
```

`i.keys` method will always return the same header or first line of your csv file in each iteration.